# get variable's value in if conditional Batch Script

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, token, wildcard

I have a batch script will do these things:

1. List all the MAC
2. Check if the current folder has the XML file like "blah-blah-[MAC].xml"
3. If Yes --> execute setup.exe and pass that XML file as an argument (XML files are in a folder name "config")

And this is my batch script:

```
for /F  "usebackq tokens=12 delims= "  %%i IN (`ipconfig /all ^| find /i "physical address"`) DO if exist *%%i.xml (setup.exe /file:config\*%%i.xml)
```

The problem is, when i use the wildcard "*%%i.xml", i can not get the value in the if conditional.

-> How can i pass that matched "***%%i.xml**" XML file to the setup.exe in this case ?

Comment: What error do you see?  If your setup.exe doesn't accept wildcards like that then you need an extra loop to parse each filename.

Comment: when i pass *%%i.xml like that, my setup.exe says *MAC.xml, but not blah-blah-MAC.xml ( i want blah-blah-MAC.xml ) <-- this is error, i dont have file *MAC.xml, i have blah-blah-MAC.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works for me, if I change `tokens=12` to `tokens=10` (german Windows).

But what about:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F  "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%i IN (`ipconfig /all ^| findstr "..-..-..-"`) DO ( 
    set file=*%%i.xml
    set file=!file: =!
    for %%a in (!file!) do echo %%a
)
```

It takes the `:` as delimiter. Only "Problem" is that there is a leading space, but that can easily be solved. (the string "physical address" changes in lenght in other languages, so the number of tokens will vary if you delimit with spaces)

The `for %%a` line is the extra-loop, that foxidrive suggested.

Note: replacing `find /i "physical address"` with `findstr "..-..-..-"` makes it language-independend.

Comment: Thanks, btw, i cant use findstr with my enviroment. And "physical address" is ok. Can you fix the code by using my code's "For statement"(keep token, delims, using "find /i" and "physical address" ). I tried but get stuck at "set file=!file: =!"